# Corresponding Spring JPA method name for requesting a random row in SQL

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

In order to get the a record in an SQL table with a `name`, I am using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE User.name = name;
```

And the corresponding **Spring** **JPA** method name is the following:

```
UserEntity findUserByName(@Param("name") String name);
```

**My question** is the following:

How can I request a random record from an SQL table?
I know that my SQL query should be the following:

```
SELECT * FROM User
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

But, what should be the **corresponding Spring JPA method name** for that?

```
UserEntity findUserXXXXXXX (XXXXXXX);
```

Answer (score 14):

JPA supports functions which are defined in specification. You can use `native query` option or `JPA 2.1 function` to call database functions which are not directly supported by the JPA specification. You can use `@Query` annotation in your spring data jpa repository.

**Native Query**

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM User ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1", nativeQuery = true)
UserEntity findUser();
```

**Function**

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM UserEntity u order by function('RAND')")
List<UserEntity> findUser();
```

You can use list.get(0) to get the single user.

Comment: Using a native query defeats the purpose of `JPA` / `Hibernate` as the `RAND` function is specific to MySQL

Answer (score 0):

if you want to random a list you can easily do it by using `PagingAndSortingRepository` and provide a random page number where (page_number < page_count)

e.g

```
long page_count = (totalRecords / perPage)
//Use PageRequest for PagingAndSortingRepository Pageable object
PageRequest.of(new Random().nextLong(page_count), perPage)
```

or you can provide the random page number from front_end side